# Setting the Name-attriubute on a custom control results in compilation error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a very simple wpf custom control that defines two constructors:

```
public class SomeControl : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
    public SomeControl() 
    {
    }

    public SomeControl(ISomeService service)
    {
    }
}
```

This control is defined in a class library called *ControlLib*. The ISomeService interface is defined in another class library project called *ServiceContracts* and *ControlLib* has a reference to it.

The third project in the solution (called *FrontEnd*) is a simple WPF-project and i place the custom control on the MainWindow like this:

```
<Window x:Class="FrontEnd.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ControlLib;assembly=ControlLib"
    Height="450"
    Width="800">
<Grid>
    <controls:SomeControl />
</Grid>
```

Until now, everything works fine and as intended. The project structure looks roughly like this:
[image: Diagram that show the project structure]

The problem occurs when i give the costum control a name. When i set the **Name** attribute like this `<controls:SomeControl x:Name="OhWhy" />` the project does not longer compile. I get the following error:

> Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'ServiceContracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event. Line 8 Position 31.' FrontEnd    C:\01_Data\Tmp\SomeSolution\FrontEnd\MainWindow.xaml    8

**My question is:** Why does it break when i add the *Name*-attribute and why does it work in the first place?

I know that setting the Name-attribute will add a field to the designer generated *.g.i.cs file to access the control from code behind, but compilation also breaks when i do the same in a template in some resource dictionary without any designer generated files.

The following things solved the problem but im not exactly sure why:

- Adding a reference in *FrontEnd* to *ServiceContracts*
- Making the parametrized constructor internal

Comment: This is caused by the XAML compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823460/cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-postsharp-because-it-has-not-been-preloa. The solution is to add a reference to ServiceContracts.dll.

Comment: oh wow... didn't know that the xaml compiler loads dependencies... thx for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the XAML compiler. Please refer to the following question for more information.

[Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'PostSharp' because it has not been preloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823460/cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-postsharp-because-it-has-not-been-preloa)

The solution is to add a reference to `ServiceContracts.dll` from the WPF application project.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening with giving it a name is that you get a local member variable of type SomeControl in FrontEnd.  This pulls in the dependency.  Before that, you just have baml in a resource and when the baml is deserialized at runtime, the SomeControl type is already loaded in the AddDomain and can be dynamically instantiated using reflection.